# GPU device Id Mismatch while calling from keras

Tags: cuda, gpu, deep-learning, theano, keras

I have got a GPU device ID mapping problem.

When I set `device = gpu0` in `.theanorc` for keras (theano as backend), my neural network is actually running on gpu3.

However, when I set `device = gpu3`, my neural network is actually running on `gpu0`.

(The gpu status are checked through `"nvidia-smi"`)

I have googled a lot, but got nothing.

Comment: The listing order in nvidia-smi does not necessarily match the enumeration order of GPUs in CUDA (which is what theano order refers to.)  You seem to be reporting an observation here but not actually asking a question.  This is expected behavior.  If you want to see the expected ordering of GPUs on your machine for CUDA, run the CUDA `deviceQuery` sample.  The ordering of GPUs listed there should be the CUDA ordering.

Comment: Thanks! this is actually what I meant to ask.

Do you know by any chance how could we change the order in nvidia-smi?

Comment: `nvidia-smi` reports the GPUs in their PCI enumeration order.  That method of reporting cannot be changed.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks a lot @RobertCrovella